# How to redirect non-www and www domain with specific sub folder to root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I have 3 domain names:**

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
```

**They all share the same sub folder URL:**

```
www.domain1.com/sub1/sub2
www.domain2.com/sub1/sub2
www.domain3.com/sub1/sub2
```

**I need to redirect everything in sub2 and below it to the site's homepage:**

```
www.domain1.com/sub1/sub2  --> www.domain1.com
domain1.com/sub1/sub2 --> www.domain1.com


www.domain2.com/sub1/sub2  --> www.domain2.com
domain2.com/sub1/sub2 --> www.domain2.com


www.domain3.com/sub1/sub2  --> www.domain3.com
domain3.com/sub1/sub2 --> www.domain3.com
```

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain3\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub1/sub2(.*)$ / [NC,L,R=301]
```

**Problem:**
It's only working for `www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com`.

It does not work for URLs without the "www".  So does not work: `domain1.com/sub1/sub2`

Thanks!

Comment: Simplify it to one condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com$ [NC]` and use the same `RewriteRule` as you have. Same problem, or does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, the condition performs the same as my original rules.  So non-www domains still don't redirect properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sub1/sub2/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://%{HTTP_HOST}/     [R=301,L]
```

Redirects any URL with this scheme

`http://www.domain1.com/sub1/sub2` or `http://domain1.com/sub1/sub2`

To corresponding root, removing the segment `/sub1/sub2`.

I assumed `/sub1/sub2` are fixed strings. If they aren't, replace

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sub1/sub2/?  [NC]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/?  [NC]
```

The URL scheme with 2 folders in the path `/sub1/sub2/` must be kept for the rule to work.

Comment: I tried this bit using specified /sub1/sub2/ folder paths.  It doesn't seem to work. This rule seems to be the problem: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sub1/sub2/?$  [NC]` When changed to as below, it works as my original rules: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sub1/sub2(.*)$  [NC]`

Comment: Also to clarify, these rules are the only entries in my htaccess file, so no other rules can be a factor in affecting these rules. And... I'm using XAMPP v3.1.0 as my environment with apache's virtual host setup with the domains pointing to the root where this htaccess file exists. The domains are all pointing to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file.

Comment: Could you please copy-paste in a comment the complete URL used to test?

Comment: I cannot disclose the domain names publicly.  However, I would assume string literals work the same in regular expressions.  So here's how a URL look like (the domain and sub folders are only lower case a-z.  No fancy characters): `http://www.domain1.com/sub1/sub2/something_random` and the non-www URL version: `http://domain1.com/sub1/sub2/something_random` Where something_random can be anything.  So long as it has `/sub1/sub2/`, it should be redirected.

Comment: No need to disclose private information. Only **patterns** are important and here is the first problem: `/sub1/sub2/something_random` scheme is different from the one in your question `/sub1/sub2`. There is nothing obvious when working with redirection. Anyway, I modified my answer to work with this URL scheme and it will work as long as nothing else is different. I don't think a local server can replicate the URL structure you describe in your question, for example. Maybe you should test directly in your web server or update the question with the real requirements and testing conditions.